# NGINX reverse proxy for HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: nginx, https, reverse-proxy

[Link to HTTP to HTTPS proxy picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzdoA.png)

I am maintaining an application on a legacy platform which can make HTTP GET and POST calls out to web services, but not secure HTTPS with the latest ciphers.

The external service provider has started requiring HTTPS with TLS 1.2 or 1.3 strong ciphers, which leaves the legacy platform unable to exchange data with it.

Until the legacy app can be reworked or replaced to use HTTPS & TLS 1.2, the stopgap solution I've been working on is to use an NGINX server as a reverse proxy to transform HTTP connections from inside the building to outgoing HTTPS (see picture).

Using the proxy in this way works with a browser initiating HTTP calls to the proxy, but fails with the legacy app because apparently the proxy is passing through the encrypted HTTPS response to the legacy app, instead of transforming the HTTPS response back into plain-text HTTP.

Is it possible to configure NGINX to do transform HTTP to HTTPS in this way, and if yes how is it done?